# Sinônimo de 'where' em inglês

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, tradução-inglês

Quando estamos descrevendo, por exemplo, símbolos usados numa equação:

> *E* = *mc*²,
> *em que* *E* é energia, *m*, massa, e *c* a velocidade da luz.

usamos em português as palavras 'em que', 'no qual', 'na qual' e etc. Porém, no inglês me parece que a única alternativa é 'where'. Há algum sinônimo em inglês para 'where' para ser usado no contexto que descrevi acima?

As vezes fica repetitivo o uso da palavra 'where' dentro de um mesmo texto e/ou contexto.

Comment: "E = mc², in which c is the speed of light in a vacuum" ou "E = mc², of which the c is the speed of light in a vacuum"? Eu honestamente acho que essa repetição de "where" não é um problema -- pelo menos, para mim, não me soa mal.

Comment: @Schilive É que na língua portuguesa não é elegante essa repetição de palavras. Não sei se isso é também aplicável ao inglês.

Comment: @Schilive 'in which' não seria melhor empregado no lugar de 'no qual/nos quais'? Me parece estranho 'in which c is the speed of light'. Ou isso é correto no contexto da língua inglesa?

Comment: Guilherme, acho que a repetição pode ser deselegante, mas às vezes não faz diferença, como com artigos e preposições. Por exemplo, se colocares uma fórmula por parágrafo com “where [...]”, acho que não me soaria mal; para mim, “where [...]” para fórmulas repetido não é deselegante, por mais que pareça, principalissimamente para o escritor. Esse “which” (que/qual) estaria no lugar de “E = mc²”, então, “E = mc². In which c is [...]” = “E = mc². In E = mc², c is [...]” = “E = mc², no qual c é [...]” = “E = mc². Em E = mc², c é[...]”. Não confies na minha pontuação em inglês, por sinal.

Comment: **where** in English refers to the location of the letter or symbol in the overall equation. In which is not used here usually. And there is no need to repeat the word *where*.  E = mc², where E stands for energy, m for mass and c for the speed of light. See? No repetition.

Comment: Just like Portuguese where you do not repeat em que, either....Não entendo porque você pensa que é preciso repetir where.....

Comment: @Lambie Mas eu não disse que quero repetir e sim que quero evitar a repetição ao longo de um texto, e para isso gostaria de usar sinônimos da palavra 'where' (caso existam).

Comment: There is no other way, **just like Portuguese**.

Answer (score 4):

Existem várias alternativas. Deixo aqui apenas algumas das que considero, por experiência própria, mais comuns:

> 1. *In this expression,* *c* is the speed of light, m is the mass and E is the rest energy.
> 2. *where* *c* is the speed of light, m is the mass and E is the rest energy.
> 3. *Here*, *c* represents the speed of light, m, the mass and E, the rest energy.
> 4. with *c* *being* the speed of light, m, the mass and E, the rest energy.

Comment: 2 of those are false. Bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer coisa relacionada a números matemáticos, usamos "Where" em vez de "Which", soa muito esquisto usar "Which" mesmo.

Comment: Nem 'in which' não fica legal? Assim como no português é ruim a repetição de 'where'?

Answer (score 0):

sinonimo de "where" mais proximo, seria "onde"

Comment: Mas vale notar que os puristas reclamam do "onde" quando não se refere a um lugar físico e consideram errado seu uso numa situação como a da OP.

Comment: Exato. Em língua portuguesa, dependendo do contexto, é errado usar 'onde'.